# Presto SQL get yyyymm minus 2 months

Tags: sql, datetime, left-join, presto, date-arithmetic

I am using Presto. I have an integer column (let's call the column 'mnth_nbr') showing year and month as: yyyymm. For instance, 201901. I want to have records showing all dates AFTER 201901 as well as 2 months before the given date. In this example, it would return 201811, 201812, 201901, 201902, 201903, etc. Keep in mind that my data type here is integer.

This is what I have so far (I do a self join):

```
select ... 
from table 1 as first_table
left join table 1 as second_table 
on first_table.mnth_nbr = second_table.mnth_nbr
where first_table.mnth_nbr <= second_table.mnth_nbr
```

I know this gives me all dates AFTER 201901, including 201901. But, I don't know how to add the 2 previous months (201811 and 201812)as explained above.

Answer (score 4):

As far as the documentation, [Presto DB `date_parse` function](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) expects a MySQL-like date format specifier.

So the proper condition for your use case should be :

```
SELECT ...
FROM mytable t
WHERE 
    date_parse(cast(t.mnth_nbr as varchar), '%Y%m') >= date '2019-01-01' - interval '2' month
```

**Edit**

As commented by Piotr, a more optimized expression (index-friendly) would be :

```
WHERE 
    mnth_nbr >= date_format(date '2019-01-01' - interval '2', '%Y%m')
```

Comment: I would use rather put it differently, `mnth_nbr >= date_format(date '2019-01-01' - interval '2', '%Y%m')`, so that predicate pushdown can work

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen : yes, thanks for pointing this out, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would help. first parse your int to date

```
date_parse(cast(first_table.mnth_nbr as varchar), 'yyyymm') > date '2019-01-01' - interval '2' month
```

please keep in mind that you may encounter with indexing issues with this approach.